# Best Practices for Handling Exception when calling forward on a RequestDispatcher

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets

I was wondering if there is a best practice or pattern when it comes to how to handle a ServletException if it is thrown when trying to call the forward() method on a RequestDispatcher object. Is there something I configure within the web.xml file that can handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if that example: http://mrbool.com/how-to-create-error-page-in-j2ee/26770 is enough sophisticated, but JEE offers you specify in web.xml that concrete exception must be handled by particular servlet or JSP page and customize error handling in the servlet/JSP